# using c# code blocks in aspx page - make variables available between blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, block

I have an aspx page with some c# code blocks in it and I am trying to use a variable from the first block in the second block. I've tried lots of different things to make the variable public and available but haven't managed it. Can someone point out/give me a clue as to where I am going wrong please?

This is some of my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<%
  string myVar;          
  myVar = ”Dan”;
%>

<script>

function buildHyperlinks(){
    try{
        $(<a href ='http://myServer/sites/page.aspx?params=<% Response.Write(myVar);%>'>"`
    }catch(err){
        setTimeout(buildHyperlinks(), 5000); 
    }       
}


</script>
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your variable inside **script runat="server"** directive, like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    string myVar = "Dan";
</script>
```

This varibče should be available through all your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not decalre your variable in your code-behind? Then it should be available everywhere.

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what you mean by code behind? if you mean code behind this page I don't have any yet I suppose I could include some but I'm not sure how...

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, it should always create ans .aspx and .cs file together. The Code-Behind file is linked in the <%@ Page Language="C#"%>. This is a good tutorial:  [Code-Behind Model Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247/en)

Comment: Ahh - I'll give that a try and post my results - Im not using visual studio just a text editor.